# Swift Vapor Cookies not working

Tags: swift, cookies, session-cookies, vapor

I am trying to create cookies, but I am not seeing any cookie in browser. Instead of that I am getting different output on Postman & different output on chrome browser.

blow is how I code to create cookies.

1. Create route

   ```
   drop.get("create", handler:createCookie)
   ```
2. Handler

   ```
   func createCookie(request: Request) throws -> ResponseRepresentable {

   let cookie = Cookie(name: "login", value:"value", expires: generateExpirationDate(), secure: true)
   request.cookies.insert(cookie)

   return "Done"
   }
   ```
3. below is func to create expiration handler

   ```
    func generateExpirationDate() -> Date {
     return Date() + (60 * 1) // 1 Minutes later
    }
   ```

**In post man I am getting one cookie named "vapor-sessions"** 
[image]

**And in chrome browser I am getting two cookies as in below picture.**
[image]

**But my desired one is not there. !!!!!!!**

**EDIT**:

**I also have tried below code but no luck for Postman, but this one 'works in chrome', I have doubt for other browsers !!!!**

```
func createCookie(request: Request) throws -> ResponseRepresentable {

    let cookie = Cookie(name: "login", value:"value", expires: generateExpirationDate(), secure: true)

    let response = try Response(status: .ok, json: JSON(node: [
        "yo": "yoyo"
        ]))

    response.cookies.insert(cookie)


    return response
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your pre-edit code is not working because you are adding the cookie to the `request`, not the `response`. The response is what is sent to the browser, so that is the right place to set the cookie.

Here is a full example:

```
import Foundation
import Cookies
import HTTP
import Vapor

let drop = Droplet()

drop.get("create") { request in
  let response = Response(status: .ok)
  let expiry = Date(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60)
  let cookie = Cookie(name: "login", value: "value", expires: expiry)
  response.cookies.insert(cookie)
  return response
}

drop.run()
```

Using `curl` to check the headers sent by Vapor, you can clearly see where the cookie is being set.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Set-Cookie: login=value; Expires=Sat, 14 Jan 2017 05:31:32 GMT; Path=/
Date: Sat, 14 Jan 2017 05:30:32 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

Comment: But as I say returning response with cookie will not work for Postman app, and I have doubt for other browsers too. I will try this on all popular browsers and and will Update my question again.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a complete, runnable example. If a client application is not respecting the cookie, that is up to the client, not the server. Vapor is sending the correct header. It should be safe for all common browsers.

Answer (score 2):

on local environment the cookies not run, I had same problem with Postman, you can try on real environment, for example with Heroku, it's free.

Maybe for you test cookies that use Postman application [Interceptor Cookies plugin](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/interceptor_cookies).

This code works for me, I'm using Middleware controller for set cookie..

```
let auth = AuthMiddleware(user: User.self) { value in
        return Cookie(
            name: "your_cookie_name",
            value: value,
            expires: Date().addingTimeInterval(60 * 60 * 5), // 5 hours
            secure: true,
            httpOnly: true
        )
    }
    drop.middleware.append(auth)
```

I hope I've been helpful